# Build only modified packages with Colcon, ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, build, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using ROS 2 bouncy built from source on Ubuntu 18.04 and I was wondering if there was a command to only build the modified packages with colcon similar to how catkin worked (tell me if I'm wrong ??) on ROS 1 ?

I found the `colcon build --packages-select <name-of-pkg>` command to only build the selected package and the `colcon build --packages-up-to <name-of-pkg>` to build the selected package and ALL its dependencies but it will still rebuild things like rclcpp, fastrtps and co...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298969/build-only-modified-packages-with-colcon,-ros2/) by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2018-07-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) on 2018-07-29**:
Which `catkin` command are you referring to that you want an equivalent for?

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2018-07-29**:
Haven't use ros 1 in quite some time, but I remember that `catkin_make` would just build the modified packages ?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-29**:
`catkin_make` is different because it invokes CMake only once and within CMake adds the directory of each package. This approach doesn't scale well since it might have colliding target names across packages as well as each package must declared cross packages dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm still relatively new to `colcon` myself, but as I understand it, it does not know what is inside a package other than what build system it uses, and so has no way to know if a package is modified or not. That is up to each package's own build scripts. If each package can skip its own build if there is nothing to do (as most build systems do), then `colcon` will merely be calling a build script that does nearly nothing and returns. It's not as fast as `colcon` doing the skipping, but you shouldn't be seeing packages being actually rebuilt when there is nothing changed.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2018-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2018-07-29**:
Indeed, I can't reproduce it, the command doesn't rebuild all the packages. I must have make a wrong manipulation at one point that made everything rebuild. Thanks for your time.